# Why does GMail not accept this mail?

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, gmail, pop3

I'm playing with node.js and create a smtp + pop3 server with it, just for fun.
I read about the 2 protocols on wikipedia.

My smtp server currently gets the mail and saves it to a file in a folder.
The pop3 server gets all files in this folders and sends them to the client, when he request him, without changing the email.

I used GMail to send a test mail to the smtp server. This worked well.
I also used GMail to retrieve the mail. GMail said then, that 1 mail was retrieved,
but the mail does not appear in the mail-list. I think, that GMail does not accept the mail, even if it has successfully fetched it.

The mail looks like this:

```
Received: by gxk1 with SMTP id 1so3430628gxk.38
        for <xxx@xxx.xx>; Mon, 05 Sep 2011 12:48:39 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=gamma;
        h=mime-version:date:message-id:subject:from:to:content-type;
        bh=iOv1lJPQPPZNBiK5+pwY5YYD+FmD8zp2fByAZA+BDDs=;
        b=jxxASTZCnyDT/J8RRQBvhMzEHFk4IxTl3kv8rFuc1ZeXNO51cr5xPouh1aNH94togQ
         amPAA3jnXymQHRFeUzz3u6871DofJTxPkOj1rY1x/iNBaSqqTE4S9mKvTzb4WF04CtvD
         tC8YY+0Yz0hBuXF6WQaTef4JLVO4blchU7UyA=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.42.135.66 with SMTP id o2mr105132ict.397.1315242079201; Mon,
 05 Sep 2011 10:01:19 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.42.220.1 with HTTP; Mon, 5 Sep 2011 10:01:19 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Mon, 5 Sep 2011 19:01:19 +0200
Message-ID: <CACUXN65OHGTE-D02sYFQ-F8CH5UcFcuYYaf92Bni6nE1khTrtA@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: asdf
From: xx Stxxutz <xx.xx@xx.xx>
To: asdf <xx@xxx.xx>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=90e6ba6e89d6ecab2204ac34a8bd

--90e6ba6e89d6ecab2204ac34a8bd
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

npiasdf

--90e6ba6e89d6ecab2204ac34a8bd
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<font size="2"><font face="verdana,sans-serif">npiasdf</font></font>

--90e6ba6e89d6ecab2204ac34a8bd--
```

What's wrong with this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve found the problem!
GMail detected, that it was the sender of the Mail, because the content was the same as the content of the previously sent mail. So he decided to delete this duplicate of the email.

I tried to send the mail form another gmail account and it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

It could be various different things, but here are my thoughts

- The content (`npiasdf`) isn't a message. It's not even a word at all, which will throw the spam filter rather a lot.
- The `To: asdf <xx@xxx.xx>` is rather dubious. I have a feeling you've modified this from the original, but this should obviously be a correct, valid email.
- Try adding proper HTML structure to your email; use `<html>` and `<body>` tags to surround your content.
- Don't use `<font>` tags; use CSS instead. This might not make GMail like your message, but `<font>` is deprecated and shouldn't generally be used.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, I've modified the email adresses, but rest of the message is original. It was generated by gmail. I simply typed some sample text. So I don't think that the message itself is invalid. I think i have to do something with it before send it to the pop3 client... But the strange thing is, that thunderbird fetched the mail successfully... the mail isn't in the smap filter, too...

Comment: Have you tried changing the first occurrence of `Content-Type` from `multipart/alternative` to `text/plain` or `text/html`?